# Is Cuba still intervening in Syria to help the Russians?

Tags: russian-federation, syria, cuba

This Daily Beast [article](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/10/16/cuba-is-intervening-in-syria-to-help-russia-it-s-not-the-first-time-havana-s-assisted-moscow.html) is now a couple of years old, dating from October 2015.  Here are the lead graphs.

> Not for the first time Cuban forces are doing Russia’s dirty work, this time in Syria. On Wednesday it was reported that a U.S. official had confirmed to Fox News that Cuban paramilitary and Special Forces units were on the ground in Syria. Reportedly transported to the region in Russian planes, the Cubans are rumoured to be experts at operating Russian tanks.
>
> For President Obama, who has staked his legacy on rapprochement  with America’s adversaries, the entrance of Cuba into the bloody Syrian civil is one more embarrassment. Russia, Iran, and Cuba—three regimes Obama has sought to bring in from the cold—are now helping to prop up the regime of Bashar al-Assad, ruler of a fourth regime he also tried in vain to court early on in his presidency. Obama has been holding his hand out in a gesture of goodwill to America’s adversaries only for them to blow him a raspberry back in his face—while standing atop a pile of Syrian corpses.

Any evidence that Cubans remain in Syria in any capacity?

Answer (score 10):

As Press Secretary Josh Earnest pointed out [at the time](https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/the-press-office/2015/10/15/press-briefing-press-secretary-josh-earnest-10152015), "we’ve seen no evidence to indicate that those reports are true." [A Cuban official also](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-mideast-crisis-cuba-idUSKCN0SC00D20151018) called the Fox News story "irresponsible and unfounded". Fidel Castro did meet with Assad as recently as 2010, but any military presence seems to have ended decades earlier.